# Can Blue card holders in Germany invest in stocks?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a blue card. Based on the document I can not have another job and I can't do my own business for two years. But I would like to know is it possible to invest in stock with Blue card?

This is not employment, however there could be profit/loss based on the situation.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but it might help to add your nationality and which countries you'd be buying stocks from, since this might affect the answers. It's also possible that this could be a question for [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) or [Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What you do with your earned and taxed money has nothing to do with residence permits or employment regulations. As to taxes for earnings or losses due to investments in stocks should be asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is not employment however there could be profit/ loss based on the situation.

As long as you invest only your own money for your own personal finances, this should be fine. what you do with your private money on private terms is none of Germany's business. You could *already* own stock or have other means of income (for example maybe you rent out property you own in your home country). Or you could simply win the lottery. Or maybe you buy a used car for yourself for cheap and manage to sell it for more than you bought it for after a year. And in the end, if you put your money into a bank account and get interest, that's not really different. *As long as it's not a business*.

Obviously, you need to declare all of this when you do your taxes, you may want to hire a tax accountant for that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. as far know there will be a 25% deduction from the profit as tax

Comment: +1 for "hire a tax accountant".  They are called *Steuerberater\*in* in German; almost everyone uses one.